# How to close run window in vim's python mode

Tags: python, vim

In vim's python mode, I could use `<leader>r` to run a python file if I am done editing this file, vim will open a new window to show the result of running this python file. It is in the bottom of the main window. My question is that after I am done to inspect the result, I want to use a shortcut to close the  window even the cursor is in current the python file , so that I don't need to switch to the result window and type `:q`.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the plugin's [source code](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/blob/bb746d0d0cba9adedbac856429e37a0dbfc599c6/autoload/pymode.vim#L62-L68), that window appears to be a preview window. Preview windows can be closed from anywhere with `:pclose` or `<C-w>z`.

See `:help preview-window`.

That information *should* be in the plugin's documentation.